# Replace datetime.now with the accessinfo.businessDate

Tags: acumatica

This is my coding and I want to change DateTime.Now to AccessInfo.businessDate:

```
  protected void SOOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
     {
       var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;

       if(row != null)
       {
         if(row.OrderType == "QT" && row.Status == "C")
         {
           row.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
         }
         else
         {
           row.RequestDate = row.OrderDate;
         }
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the answer that I want.

```
 protected void SOOrder_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
     {
       var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
       SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
       if(row != null)
       {
         if(row.OrderType == "QT" && row.Status == "C")
         {
           row.RequestDate = graph.Accessinfo.BusinessDate;
         }
         else
         {
           row.RequestDate = row.OrderDate;
         }
       }
     }
```

Comment: There is no reason to create a new instance of the graph; you're already inside a graph extension and can access Base.AccessInfo. Furthermore, do you really want to override this field in all cases? Wouldn't it make more sense to just override the FieldDefaulting handler?

Comment: @Gabriel, yes it can be that. Anyways I want to override on SOLine too but I have no idea.